# What's the difference between the two sentences?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between the two sentences?

> 1. Submitted in fulfilment of the requirements of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy at [Name] University
> 2. Submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy at [Name] University

Comment: For all practical purposes, there is none. Different universities simply have different standard phrases for this. (Though I believe you’re missing an ‘at’ in the second sentence.)

Comment: And in fact my school required (correctly, to my mind) "submitted in **partial** fulfilment..."

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, there's no real difference between the two.

However, to be pedantic about it, number 1 could mean that you submitted something in order to meet the requirements, while number 2 might indicate that you submitted it, but that it was not necessarily required.

The second example could be like someone attaching a photograph to their CV/résumé. It might increase your chances of getting the job, but it hasn't been submitted in fulfilment of the requirements.